# Is My Nginx Configuration the culprit for 500 Internal Server Errors?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, nginx-config

I've run into an issue where the Nginx configuration below returns an **internal server error** when someone visits a URL that does not exist on the server. The expected response is for the server to return a status of 404. Is there something in this configuration that would produce a status code of 500 and not 404?

Note: (actual domain has been replaced with example.com)

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- Host: Packet
- Nginx: 1.15.9

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name www.example.com;

        root /srv/www/example.com/pub;

        index index.html index.php;

        access_log /srv/www/example.com/log/access.log;
        error_log  /srv/www/example.com/log/error.log info;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbo


        location / {
                #if ($request_uri ~ ^/(.*)\.html$) {  return 301 /$1;  }
                try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php?$args;
        }

        location = / {expires max;}

        location ~* \.(?:ico|asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|css|divx|doc|docx|exe|eot|ttf|ttc|otf|woff|woff2|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|gif|gz|gzip|htc|ico|jpeg|jpg|png|js|mdb|mid|mi)$ {
                expires 1y;
                add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*";
                add_header Cache-Control "public";
        }
}

# Redirect http to https
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

# Redirect www to non-www
server {
        listen 443;
        listen [::]:443;
        server_name example.com;

        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: You should check the error log for the cause of a 5xx error, but your `try_files` statement is generating a redirection loop. You rewrite the URI to `$uri.php` but have no support for PHP  scripts.

Comment: Thank you @RichardSmith for spotting the loop. This unfortunately isn't the culprit in the server errors and the logs don't provide that information as well.